# Website returns 403 Forbidden error (NGINX) for internal traffic only

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx

I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around the issue. We have a landing page hosted on Instapaga and main site on WPEngine (Wordpress). When employees on the internal network try to access both sites, error 403 is returned.

From my location and all others I've tried (Frankfurt, London, Marseille, Vienna) it works normally. Meaning I can access both pages and go to Dashboard without a problem.

From the web research I have found the following potential causes:

- File permissions
- htaccess file
- Plugin issues
- CDN issues
- Hotlink protection

However, I cannot see how any could apply.

Do you perhaps have any ideas what could it be causing it?

Thanks,

Mat

Comment: Is the request logged by nginx (and does the log entry indicate 403)?

Comment: You may wish to add a bit more detail about the general internal setup for accessing these sites. One answer might be that only certain IPs are allowed to access the content (or some are actively disallowed) but that makes little sense for hosted services.

Comment: @grawity yes it is. Here is one the examples: [10/Oct/2019:08:04:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 189 "-" "Mozilla/5.0

Comment: @Anaksunaman sure. The website is hosted on WPEngine why DNSs are managed by Cloudflare. 

From the access logs it can be seen that only company IP is being blocked by accessing the page [ "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 189 ]. Everyone else can normally access the websites. What confuses me is that our landing page hosted by Instapage as well as Wordpress site (WPEngine) shows the same error even tough they are hosted by two separate providers.